# Using the results of an IF statement to effect 2nd IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

The results from the the first IF statement that puts out results. I would like to use the two outputted values to manipulate the second IF statement to either take the value of the `$loadedWeightUSTons` or `$emptyWeight` only one returns a value at any given time. I've tried using `$loadWeightUSTons or $emptyWeight` in each of the if or ifelse statments to no avail. Can some one be of assistance.

**1st IF Statment**

```
if ($loadWeightUSTons == 0) {
            echo "E";
        }else {
            echo "L";
        }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    if ($loadWeightUSTons == 0){
        $emptyWeight = "Not Found!";
        foreach($railunit->railUnit as $ru) {
            if((string)$ru->rvXMLfilename == $rvXMLfilename){
                $emptyWeight = (string)$ru->unitWeight;
            } 
        }
        echo $emptyWeight;
    }else{
      echo  $loadWeightUSTons;
            }
```

**2nd IF Statment**

```
if ($loadWeightUSTons <= 10) {
            echo "X";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 20){
            echo "XX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 30){
            echo "XXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 40){
            echo "XXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 50){
            echo "XXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 60){
            echo "XXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 70){
            echo "XXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 80){
            echo "XXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 90){
            echo "XXXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 100){
            echo "XXXXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 110){
            echo "XXXXXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 120){
            echo "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 130){
            echo "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 140){
            echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        } elseif ($loadWeightUSTons <= 150){
            echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        }  else{
            echo "Error!";
        }
```

Comment: So set $loadWeightUSTons to the value of $emptyWeight, if $loadWeightUSTons is zero? (Might make more sense to use a different variable name in the second code to begin with.)

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do here, output one `X` for every ten ton step? You can have that way easier … `str_repeat('X', ceil($loadWeightUSTons/10));`

Comment: @04FS essentially yes would it be possible to assign either result to a single variable to be used in the second if statement eg $weight

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking the advise from above and applied it to an IF statement which is seen below. It replaced the bulky `if` `elseif` statement.

```
 if ($loadWeightUSTons == 0){
        echo str_repeat('X', ceil($emptyWeight/10));
      }else{
        echo str_repeat('X', ceil($loadWeightUSTons/10));
      }
```

Comment: `$emptyWeight/10` makes no sense since `$emptyWeight` is a string not number.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($loadWeightUSTons > 150) {
    echo "Error!";
} else {
    echo str_repeat("X",ceil($loadWeightUSTons/10));
}
```

But I would probably recommend just to output number as is.
Having those `XXX` is not more informative than the number.
That will bring better UX.
Especially if you limit that number to 150 and you have mo long number values like `1 234 567 890` there.